# How to mount a 20 TB file system

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, lvm

I have recently created a file server with 6x4tb hard drives. One hard drive is used as the file system and is formatted with ext4. While I have created an LVM with the other five drives. This LVM system has a 20tb capacity and is formatted with XFS (I have tried with ext4 and got the same error as I am about to describe). Whenever I try to mount the drive, I get an error saying mount:file too large. The command I type in is `sudo mount /dev/DRIVE /FOLDER`. I have tried adding the filesystem parameter but it makes no difference. I am under a huge time constraint so any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer to your question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/462029/unable-to-mount-a-18tb-raid-6):

Two points:

- You must be using a 64-bit kernel to use a filesystem > 16TB due to page cache limitation.
- Version 1.41 and lower of e2fsprogs (used when formatting ext2/ext3/ext4 drives) will fail on volumes > 16TB due to software limitation.  Using a newer version of e2fsprogs will help.

In your case I think it's more likely to be the 32-bit kernel limitation.

Another option for you is simply to limit your volumes to 16 TB, for example if you don't want to run a 64-bit kernel.

Comment: I found that I had installed a 32 bit version of Ubuntu as opposed to the 64 bit version. I really appreciate your help.